# Angular6 multiple ngFor for single row - How to pass two values in one ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

In table head I have dynamic columns and search sorting functions. but for particular columns I need to disable sorting function.
In table

```
<thead>
      <tr class="table-head">
        <th *ngFor="let colName of reportColHeader; let i = index">
          {{colName}}
          <i [class]="sortIcons[colName]" (click)="toggleSort(colName, i)"></i>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

In **constructor** I have passing values as array. Not from server its static only

```
this.reportColHeader = ['ID', 'LABEL 1', 'LABEL 2', 'More'];
```

so the result will be like below

```
<tr>
 <th>ID <i></i></th>
 <th>LABEL 1 <i></i></th>
 <th>LABEL 2 <i></i></th>
 <th>More <i></i></th>
</tr>
```

Here I want to disable  (sorting function) from particular column. 
Not only last column or nth column. 
My assumption is, is possible to have one more array like

```
this.reportColHeaderOptions = ['true', 'true', 'false', 'false'];
```

by this values can show or hide the `<i></i>` 
So how can I pass this inside `ngFor`. 
**Note:** here I can't use index since the index will change. 
but I can follow **this.reportColHeader** and **this.reportColHeaderOpions** in same order.

Comment: Instead of 2 arrays you can also pass as an array of objects right? Like [{label: 'ID', isSortDisabled: true}, {label: 'LABEL 1', isSortDisabled: true}] something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `index` ? You can do this :

```
    <th *ngFor="let colName of reportColHeader; let i = index">
      {{colName}}
      <i *ngIf="reportColHeaderOpions[i]=='true'"></i>
    </th>
```

Comment: How its possible. both are in different array. so the index will work.? showing ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. since it is different array.

Comment: That means that `reportColHeaderOpions` doesn't exist in this context. Are you sure there is a `public reportColHeaderOpions = ['true', 'true', 'false', 'false'];` in your component ? Yes these are 2 different arrays but you can access them with `[i]` since `i` is just a number (0, 1, 2, 3) that you declare earlier.